# Post a form with urllib and move to that page like a web browser

Tags: django, forms, urllib2, urllib

I want to POST a form manually using urllib and redirect the user to that page as if he had clicked the submit button in a web browser.

The reason I'm doing this is because before submitting a payment to paypal, I need to store some information into the DB. Then I want to handle the user to the paypal website without having him to click again in a "Buy now" button.

I'm using Django, if this matters somehow.

is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This tool might help you: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/